# Npm hangs when I try to install a forked github repo

Tags: node.js, react-native, github, npm, npm-install

I forked a repo (https://github.com/BenJeau/react-native-draw) and tried to install it with `npm`, using

```
npm install git+https://github.com/sickopickle/react-native-draw.git
```

However, it hangs with this message:

```
reify:fsevents: timing reifyNode:node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents Completed in 36ms
```

I was able to successfully install another forked package without trouble, and the original package, https://github.com/BenJeau/react-native-draw, I could also install.

It eventually unfreezes and gives this error:

```bash
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spec')
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-27T02_39_09_898Z-debug-0.log
```

Snippet of log:

```
265 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
266 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
267 timing reifyNode:node_modules/undefined Completed in 249086ms
268 timing reify:unpack Completed in 249087ms
269 timing reify:unretire Completed in 1ms
270 timing build:queue Completed in 7ms
271 timing build:deps Completed in 8ms
272 timing build Completed in 8ms
273 timing reify:build Completed in 12ms
274 timing reify:trash Completed in 2ms
275 timing command:install Completed in 262444ms
276 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spec')
276 verbose stack     at updateNodes (C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:1225:44)
276 verbose stack     at Arborist.[saveIdealTree] (C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:1394:11)
276 verbose stack     at Arborist.reify (C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:176:31)
276 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:146:5)
276 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:134:5)
277 verbose cwd C:\Users\aiden\AwesomeProject
278 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
279 verbose node v16.18.0
280 verbose npm  v9.6.2
281 error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spec')
282 verbose exit 1
283 timing npm Completed in 262647ms
284 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1679943486276
285 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:save 1679943748710
286 verbose code 1
287 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
287 error     C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-27T18_58_06_081Z-debug-0.log
```

Note: this is for React Native, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently reported with [`npm/cli` issue 4819](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4819) and includes a few potential root causes:

> The problem was because when I started a proyect (Alpinejsx) I inmediatly used npm i nano-jsx.
> The solution was to use first npm init to create a "complete" pacakge.json file.

Or:

> The problem turned out to come from `package.json` not having a `name` property. Adding that in solved the issue for me.

Or:

> For me, this was caused by having `node.exe` next to `package.json` in the root of our tree.
> Moving it into any other directory fixed the problem.
> NPM treats wherever the node binary lives as the 'distro root' and does some special magic.

Or:

> In my case running `npm install react react-dom`.
> On my `package.json` I have these two packages as `peerDependencies`, if I move those to `devDependencies` and then run `npm install` the error is gone and all the packages are installed.
> I always have to move back those packages to `peerDependencies` after that.

Similar:

> Oddly for me it was working with `registry.npmjs.org` but not when I switched to a private mirror registry.
> The issue went away when I specified the `//legacy-peer-deps=true` option to the registry in `.npmrc`.

> If you're running into this, you could try removing individual packages one-at-a-time (and then in pairs, and then in triplets, etc.) until you no longer see this behavior, to isolate a problem dependency or set thereof, but from there the prescription would be entirely context-dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw that Github post and tried everything on there. I deleted node_modules and package-lock.json, npm clear cache --force, and did npm install. It still gives me this error. I made zero changes to the original package. Also, many of these mention the ".npmrc" file, but I don't know where that is located. I am using React Native, by the way.

Comment: @AidenYun The `.npmrc` can be ([as listed here](https://forum.mendix.com/link/space/widgets/questions/110597)) per-project, per-user (`$HOME`), global or system.

Comment: I am still getting the error. It may be due to my project setup. Can you check if the error reproduces for you as well? @VonC